# Why does my merge sort implementation return weird numbers?

Tags: c++, arrays, mergesort

The following is my code-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void MergeSort(int*,int,int);
void Merge(int*,int*,int*,int,int,int);

int main()
  {
  int a[10];
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     cin>>a[i];

  cout<<"The unsorted array is : ";
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     cout<<a[i]<<" ";

  MergeSort(a,0,10);

  cout<<"\n\n The Sorted array is : ";
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     cout<<a[i]<<" ";

  return 0;  
}

void MergeSort(int *a,int l,int h)
  {
    int m = (l+h)/2;

    int l1 = m-l;
    int h1 = h-m;

    int *lp = (int*)malloc(l1*sizeof(int));
    int *rp = (int*)malloc(h1*sizeof(int));

    for(int i=l,j=0;i<m;i++,j++)
       {
          lp[j] = a[i];
       }

    for(int i=m,j=0;i<h;i++,j++)
       {
          rp[j] = a[i];
       }

    if(l1 != 1)
      MergeSort(lp,l,m);
    if(h1 != 1)
    MergeSort(rp,m,h);

    Merge(lp,rp,a,l1,h1,(h-l));
}

void Merge(int *lp,int *rp,int *a,int l1,int h1,int b)
{
    int i,j,k;
    i=j=k=0;

    while(i<l1 && j<h1)
        {
            if(lp[i] <= rp[j])
              {
                a[k] = lp[i];
                i++;
              }
            else if(lp[i] > rp[j])
                 {
                   a[k] = rp[j];
                   j++;
                 }
            k++;
        }
    while(i<l1)
         {
            a[k] = lp[i];
            i++;k++;
         }
    while(j<h1)
         {
            a[k] = rp[j];
            j++;k++;
         }
}
```

for a given input like 1 5 2 4 3 6 7 9 8 7
output is  - 0 0 1 3 5 and then some large numbers like 46977154 etc.
I can't figure out the problem in my code.

Comment: Fyi, you're making this *much* more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Maybe because you use malloc, pointers and while loops instead of something sane like vectors, iterators and `<algorithm>`.

Comment: One or two documenting comments wouldn't hurt. How can anyone follow and understand this code? When even the guy who _wrote it_ can't, there is a problem.

Comment: OP, work it out. Follow each step of the algorithm on paper with a pen. Trace the steps as your program executes. Compare. Find out where it breaks. Then fix it. SO is a great place to obtain wisdom and knowledge but it's not a place to have people do your debugging for you simply to avoid the time and effort.

Comment: Your MergeSort function allocates memory and never deallocates it.  Also, it is called recursively, making the mermory-leak problem worse.

Comment: If you replace `int *` with `vector<int>` the debugger tells you that the third call to `MergeSort` fails because index `a[i]` with `a = {2, 4, 3}` and `i = m = 3` is out of range in the second loop.

Comment: Only thing to really say is, is, that that is a lot less difficult than you are thinking.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error:

```
MergeSort(rp,m,h)
```

This should be

```
MergeSort(rp,l,h-m)
```

The rest  is correct.